# Inconsistent sort ordering on users?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, sort

I'm trying to get a list of the 10 oldest users.  This is the endpoint I'm using:

http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/users?key=(key)&order=asc&sort=creation&pagesize=10&page=0

According to [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=oldest), they should be coming back as:

- Community
- Jarrod Dixon
- Geoff Dalgas
- Jeff Atwood
- Jon Galloway
- Joel Spolsky
- Eggs McLaren
- Kevin Dente
- Sneakers O'Toole
- Chris Jester-Young

However, the JSON I'm getting back has them in this order:

- Community
- Jeff Atwood
- Geoff Dalgas
- Jarrod Dixon
- Joel Spolsky
- Jon Galloway
- Eggs McLaren
- Kevin Dente
- Sneakers O'Toole

What gives?

**edit**

a bit more information: Jarrod, Geoff, Jeff, Jon, and Joel all have the same creation date (1217514151, or Thu, 31 Jul 2008 14:22:31 GMT).  So perhaps a better question is:

Is there defined behavior for sort ordering when two attributes have the same value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorts are not guaranteed to be stable.  Check the `creation_date` on each user to convince yourself they are in order.

Comment: Jeff, Geoff, Jarrod, Joel, and Jon all have the same creation date (`1217514151`).  I think that's what the problem is.

Comment: @Dave - its not a problem, like I said sorts are not guaranteed to be stable (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_sort#Stability)